# Windows wan remote control terminal w/o port forwarding

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, port-forwarding, tunnel

I am trying to find a solution that I can use to remotely execute Windows cmd commands. I know of PSExec from PSTools suite that's embedded into windows, but from what i understand it's made to be used when computers are on the same LAN and not outside (unless you port forward on the router). Port forwarding is not an option.

I have read on forums about the potential solution being an introduction of a server in the middle that both of the machines would connect to and it would act as a tunnel to relay the commands. The goal here is to use this kind of setup like RDP, just that i don't need the GUI part of it and i would manage the remote machine to check what applications are open, how long they have been running for etc. For example how do system administrators of many windows machines manage them remotely when being outside the LAN?

Thanks for any suggestions and tips in advance!

Comment: Side note: it's actually PowerShell and PS-Remoting is embedded into Windows – PSTools are not (and the two "PS"es have nothing in common). It's true that PSExec only _needs_ built-in Windows SMB to magically install and launch itself on the destination, but it's still a completely separate download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know of PSExec from PSTools suite that's embedded into windows, but from what i understand it's made to be used when computers are on the same LAN and not outside (unless you port forward on the router). Port forwarding is not an option.

Well no, that alone does not make it a "LAN" tool.

It is normal that port forwarding would be necessary for inbound connections when the destination is behind a NAT – the exact same thing applies to SSH, HTTP, and pretty much all protocols that are otherwise *routinely* used over the Internet.

Many remote-access tools follow the same pattern of client connecting directly to server, be it PSExec or SSH or VNC or RDP or PS-Remoting or Telnet. Some of those are used across the Internet every day, but if you're unable to configure port forwarding you'll have a hard time with them as well.

(What actually makes PSExec more LAN-oriented is that it uses the SMB and MS-RPC services in Windows, which are still considered *unsafe* to expose to the Internet – remember "Blaster" and "EternalBlue"?)

> I have read on forums about the potential solution being an introduction of a server in the middle that both of the machines would connect to and it would act as a tunnel to relay the commands. The goal here is to use this kind of setup like RDP, just that i don't need the GUI part of it and i would manage the remote machine to check what applications are open, how long they have been running for etc. For example how do system administrators of many windows machines manage them remotely when being outside the LAN?

Almost always, the answer is some sort of VPN.

For example, if all devices are in your corporate LAN but you're working from home, then it's common for the corp network to host a VPN server (with a public IP address, or at least port forwardings) that can be reached from everywhere. Once connected, the sysadmin is able to reach the entire LAN as if it was local, which allows usage of PSExec/RDP/SSH and other typical management tools.

Same goes if you have the opposite situation – when the devices are spread out and located behind NATs that the sysadmin does not control, then it is equally possible for those devices to use a VPN to connect *back* to their "base", and they become reachable as if they were in the same LAN as the sysadmin.

VPNs are not inherently unidirectional. Once the tunnel is established, it's perfectly able to carry connections from the server side to clients just as well as from client to server, and indeed between clients as well. So assuming that you're able to set up a VPN server *somewhere* (even a cloud/VPS host will do), just make your devices automatically connect out to that central server and you've completely bypassed the NAT and port-forwarding issues.

---

That said, various VPN *products* do range from generic (suitable for site-to-site links) to client-oriented. Obviously, for device management, you're looking for something which supports automatic connection (and ideally certificate-based credentials) and works in split-tunnel mode by default. You might even end up using two completely different VPN products for devices and for employees/sysadmins.

(If the devices are Windows computers, then OpenVPN or *maybe* WireGuard would be my top choices, though I've also used ZeroTier and Tinc for the purpose.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the informative answer! It sounds like the VPN is the way forward and i will take a look into setting one up.